# React, calling a function before render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an async function to call before render

(the async function fetches firebase RemoteConfig and I want to use the value when rendering)

Now, I have the following structure

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await remoteConfig.fetch() 
}
```

Problem is that the `fetch` call is not guaranteed to be called before `render` (in my test)

How do I make sure to fetch the data before `render()`?

Comment: You don't, you tolerate the fact that it might not be there the first time you render. Or you can look into https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html, but it's experimental.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute function before render, I think there are other hooks like getDerivedStateFromProps . But calling api before render is generally not recommended. Using componenDidMount is good, you should structure you code like:

```
componentDidMount(async () => {const res = await fetch(//your api)})
```

Once you receive the data, you call `this.setState` to update your state and react will automatically update the UI